# Record Video and capture Image in Android

Tags: android, image, video, record

I am developing an application where I need to have constant Camera running inside my app
So I have two things to achieve here,
1. Capture Image
2. Record Video

I am having difficulties to record video and stop and reset camera

Following is snippet of my code:-

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Myvideo1 extends Activity  implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
     //   stopRecording();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    public MediaRecorder mrec = new MediaRecorder();    
    private Camera mCamera;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
   //     if(mCamera==null)
    //        mCamera = Camera.open();

        // Please maintain sequence of following code. 

        // If you change sequence it will not work.

        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        try {
            startRecording();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {

        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Start");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

    {
        if(item.getTitle().equals("Start"))
        {
            try {

                startRecording();
            //    item.setTitle("Stop");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                String message = e.getMessage();
                Log.i(null, "Problem " + message);
                mrec.release();
            }
        }

        else
        //  if(item.getTitle().equals("Stop"))
        {
          //  mrec.stop();
         //   mrec.release();
         //   mrec = null;
          //  item.setTitle("Start");
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    protected void startRecording() throws IOException
    {
        if(mCamera==null)
            mCamera = Camera.open();

         String filename;
         String path;

         path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();

         Date date=new Date();
         filename="/rec"+date.toString().replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_")+".mp4";

         //create empty file it must use
         File file=new File(path,filename);

        mrec = new MediaRecorder(); 

        mCamera.lock();
        mCamera.unlock();

        // Please maintain sequence of following code. 

        // If you change sequence it will not work.
        mrec.setCamera(mCamera);    
        mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);     
        mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mrec.setOutputFile(path+filename);
        mrec.setMaxDuration(10000);     //10 sec



  //  }


    mrec.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {   
        @Override  
        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {  
            if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {   
                onStop();    

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "video of 10 sec is completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }  
        }
    }
    ); 

    }


    public void preparerec()
    {
         try {
            mrec.prepare();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(this.surfaceHolder);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void startrec()
    {
         mrec.start();
    }





    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {      

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();      
        parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);     
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);       
        mCamera.startPreview(); 


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {       

       /* if (mCamera != null) {
            Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            mCamera.setParameters(params);

            Log.i("Surface", "Created");
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera not available!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            finish();
        }*/


         try                 {      
             //Open the Camera in preview mode            
            mCamera = Camera.open(); 
            preparerec();
            //        
             }              
         catch(Exception ioe)          
             {          
             ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);          
             } 

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();       

    }


    public void onStop(){
        mrec.stop();
        mrec.release();
        mrec = null;
     //   item.setTitle("Start");
    }


}
```

When I StartRecording the Screen gets flickering and green on my samsung Galaxy s2,s any solution on this?

Comment: is there any exception/error you are getting?

Comment: When I StartRecording the Screen gets blurr any solution on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This Solution](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/App/android-in-practice/com/manning/aip/media/VideoRecorderActivity.java.htm) works perfect for me.

Comment: "This solution" is no longer a valid link.

Comment: Please, fix thi link. It is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a camera object both in onCreate (in startRecording - that'll always run before surfaceCreated), and then in surfaceCreated.  Only open the camera once; the second time will throw an exception.

I'd recommend moving your recording code to all run when a user hits a button, to start with; you've split the setup work over 2-3 methods that are all triggered at different times, and you're assuming quite a bit about the order in which they're called.

If you need to start recording immediately when the app starts, I'd recommend having each callback check if all the others have completed, and then firing up recording.